# Replace string form getUrlParameter function

Tags: javascript, string, variables, url, replace

I have a question about the getUrlParameter. I'm retrieving the brand and model name of the URL (e.g. http://www.example.com/?model=SM-9675&brand=Samsung).
But I want to change the brand name like this; If the brandname is 'Samsung', replace Samsung with 'Microsoft'. How can I do this?

Javascript code:

```
<script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

var brand = getUrlParameter('brand'); //Place brand in var
var model = getUrlParameter('model'); //Place model in var

document.getElementById('brandmodel').innerHTML = brand + " " + model; //place brand and model in HTML.
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="brandmodel"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `if` statement:

```
if (brand === 'Samsung') {
  brand = 'Microsoft';
}
```